# Unity Canvas button not working

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I added a canvas component to one of my images to override default layer order sorting. Turns out the button controls on that panel have stopped working?

Has anyone any idea about this in Unity? I am using unity 5.5.2.

Comment: Adding a canvas to an object can mess up a lot of things. In this case, it's not so much that the button controls have stopped working, but that the mouse clicks are being captured by the top-most parent canvas and not falling through to child canvases.

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way to debug is to :

1. Run the game in the editor, not in full screen (uncheck [Maximize On Play button](http://www.middlevr.com/doc/1.2/images/maximise.png))
2. Select the [`EventSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) GameObject of your scene
3. In the inspector, open the Preview Window and make it big enough
4. Move your mouse on your screen, and check if the name of your buttons appear next to the field `pointerEnter`

[image: EventSystem]

If you can't see it, here are possible solutions :

1. Make sure you don't have any UI elements above your button which could block the raycasts
2. Make sure you have enabled raycasting on the images used by your buttons (check [RaycastTarget](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-raycastTarget.html))

[image: Raycast target]

3. Make sure you have an [`EventSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) in your scene
4. Make sure you have a callback attached to your buttons so as to trigger your functions
5. Make sure you don't have any [`CanvasGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) with `BlocksRaycast` or `Interactable` set to false
6. Make sure you have a [`GraphicRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html) attached on a gameobject (on the Canvas usually)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to fix my issue. Also learned how to debug with event system preview window.

Comment: thanks I couldn't understand why this was happening but the first thing you said helped me there was an text above my button preventing from interacting thank you again

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I did not know that you have add a Graphic Raycaster component as well. Started taking input after that.

Thanks everyone.