# Unity: UI button not unclickable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing an android game which has 2 levels, I made two joystick button that controls the main player using the simple joystick plugin and made a prefab of it and imported it in level 2, the problem is that the joysticks are working without any error with empty `OnClick()` in level 1 but are unclickable in level 2 (The scene already has an `EventSystem`).

**Hierarchy**

[image]

**Move Button**

[image]

**Fire/Rotate button**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850003/unity-canvas-button-not-working/46853063#46853063)?

Comment: Yes just tried them. no help !!!!

Comment: changing the sort order work....thank you its was blocked by other Layer !!!