# Unity PauseMenu doesn't work in second level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a pause menu for my game. In level1 my pause menu works, but in level2 if you press esc it appears but the buttons aren't interactive for some reason. I copied the canvas from level.

```
public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public string levelSelect;
    public string mainMenu;
    public bool isPaused;
    public GameObject pauseMenuCanvas;

    void Start (){

    }

    void Update () {

        if(isPaused)
        {
            pauseMenuCanvas.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        } else {
            pauseMenuCanvas.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            isPaused = !isPaused;
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        isPaused = false;
    }

    public void LevelSelect()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(levelSelect);
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(mainMenu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an EventSystem?

Comment: no never used that and dont know what that is, but i dont understand why it works in my first level but not in the second one

Comment: @MartijnVerkerke when you check the GameObject list in the Editor of your first level, their should be an EventSystem Object

Comment: ye thats in level1 should i copy it to level 2?

Comment: @MartijnVerkerke yes, you always need this. Normally it is created automatically, when you create a UI Object, but because you copied it, this did not happen

Comment: @Sebastian Kilb thank you very much

Comment: @MartijnVerkerke glad to help you out. I also had to learn these kind of mistakes as well as your previously problem. :)

Comment: I'd suggest you post it as an answer instead of a comment @SebastianKilb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Canvas button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850003/unity-canvas-button-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add EventSystem 
The EventSystem allows you to interact with buttons